# How to build hasura graphql query with join for condition?

Tags: graphql, hasura

I have 2 tables with - users and users_ban, so I want to make graphql using hasura server query which fetch users and join boolean field either user in ban list, like in sql:

```
select 
id, 
email,
case
  when users_ban.id is null then false
  else true
end is_banned
from users
left join users_ban
on users.id = users_ban.user_id;
```

How can I do it via graphql and hasura server?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom SQL function with any query you need and track it in Hasura to extend your GraphQL schema.
Take a look here: `https://hasura.io/docs/latest/schema/postgres/custom-functions/#use-cases`